# Where can I publish a longer short story (9000 words)?

Tags: fiction, publishing, short-story, contests

I wrote a short story that's 9135 words long. I'd like to enter it into a contest or publishing. I have seen that most only accept stories from 500-2000 words. Does anyone know of any contests/publishers that take that length of a story? It's fiction by the way.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *SamtheMan*! Interesting question. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have more of a novella, or mini novel. Try looking for novella contests or publishing opportunities.

- W.W. Norton Publishes an anthology called the Norton Reader every year.
- Reedsy has opportunities
- The Kindle Store can publish anything, really

Really, you could just research publishers like you normally would, but as a short story author, rather than a novelist. There are plenty of publishers that work with that kind of material.